# Coupling words that express uncertain things with "will", which indicates likelihood or certainty

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, expressions, modality

The following quotation is from Anthony Trollope's *The Small House at Allington*:

> But it seems as though she will be so far separated from us. It is not the distance, but the manner of life which makes the separation. I hope you'll never be taken so far from me.

The expressions **it seems** and **as though** both indicate or give the impression of something that is uncertain, irreal or hypothetical, that is, is not palpable or tangible.

On the other hand **will** indicates a strong likelihood or certainty, yet they are coupled together.

The whole thing puzzles me, I just can't understand the way they are doing properly their jobs in the sentence in question.

If I were to write that sentence I would probably use **would** instead of **will** but I'm not sure of both the author's reasons and if my suggestion might be correct.

Would you please throw some light on this so as to help me understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use 'would' in a sentence like that if I was discussing something that might or might not happen:

> **If** she goes, it seems as though she **would** be so far separated from us.

On the other hand, I would be more likely to use the author's construction if it was something that was definitely going to happen, and I was talking about what I thought the result would be:

> **When** she goes, it seems as though she **will** be so far separated from us.

The use of 'will' indicates that the *event* is certain to happen, while the weaker 'it seems as though' indicate that the *results of that event* are subjective and/or uncertain.

It's also worth noting that 'will' does not *have* to imply a strong certainty. It indicates that the speaker/author has no reason to signal *un*certainty, but it's a default option as much as a positive signal. If a positive indication of certainty is needed, most people will add an extra modifier such as 'will definitely' or 'will obviously'.

Answer (score 1):

> But it seems as though she will be so far separated from us. It is not
>   the distance, but the manner of life which makes the separation. I
>   hope you'll never be taken so far from me.

*It seems...*

**It feels (to me)...** or **It appears (to me)...**

*...as though she will be so far separated from us.*

**as if she is going to be separated from us by a great distance.**

The "as though" is an acknowledgement (like  "as if") that the separation is not *literally* by a great distance. It is the "manner of life" that will separate them.

Answer (score 1):

The word **will** in this sentence simply indicates *future* tense, not *certainty*. The sentence is saying that it seems likely or possible that something **will** happen sometime in the future.

For example, if I see you packing your bags, I might say, "It seems as though you will be going on a trip." I don't know for sure, but it seems probable. And you're not on the trip yet -- I'm just guessing that you **will** go.

Consider these additional examples where **will** doesn't indicate certainty:

> I doubt I will go to the lake tomorrow.
>
> I don't think he will ever walk again.
>
> Do you think I will win the lottery?